# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 and Phonegap

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I have a Static iOS Library which uses Phonegap as a component. ( I follow the steps provided by the documentation), I can compile the library alone without problems.
Now I try to use my static library in an iOS Application.
So I have my App which have a project reference to my static library which have an project reference to phonegap.
It looks like

- App
- - Library
- - - Phonegap

Now when I want to compile I get many errors and all look like:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_kUTTypeVideo", referenced from:
  -[CDVCapture captureVideo:] in libmyLibrary.a(CDVCapture.o)
```

I try to change the valid architectures in many combinations and the switch build valid architectures only but nothing works.

Its no ARC Project if it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently found the problem, I have to import all the frameworks that described in the phonegap documentation not only in the static library that uses phonegap but rather also in the main app.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that cordova library you are using is not armv7 compatible. Use latest cordova library that is compatible with armv7 architecture.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue...it seems that you are using older version of PhoneGap (say 1.2 ...). The only solution to this issue is to use Cordova library (the latest one), which resolved my issue.